# Differences and relationship between glActiveTexture and glBindTexture

Tags: opengl, textures

From what I gather, `glActiveTexture` sets the active "texture unit". Each texture unit can have multiple texture targets (usually GL_TEXTURE_1D, 2D, 3D or CUBE_MAP).

If I understand correctly, you have to call `glActiveTexture` to set the texture unit first (initialized to `GL_TEXTURE0`), and then you bind (one or more) "texture targets" to that texture unit?

The number of texture units available is system dependent. I see enums for up to 32 in my library. I guess this essentially means I can have the lesser of my GPU's limit (which I think is <del>16</del> 8) and 32 textures in GPU memory at any one time? I guess there's an additional limit that I don't exceed my GPU's maximum memory (supposedly 1 GB).

Am I understanding the relationship between texture targets and texture units correctly? Let's say I'm allowed 16 units and 4 targets each, does that mean there's room for 16*4=64 targets, or does it not work like that?

Next you typically want to load a texture. You can do this via `glTexImage2D`. The first argument of which is a texture target. If this [works like `glBufferData`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8691709/65387), then we essentially bind the "handle"/"texture name" to the texture target, and then load the texture data into that target, and thus indirectly associate it with that handle.

What about `glTexParameter`? We have to bind a texture target, and then choose that same target again as the first argument? Or does the texture target not need to be bound as long as we have the correct active texture unit?

`glGenerateMipmap` operates on a target too...that target has to still be bound to the texture name for it to succeed?

Then when we want to draw our object with a texture on it, do we have to *both* choose an active texture unit, and then a texture target? Or do we choose a texture unit, and then we can grab data from any of the 4 targets associated with that unit? This is the part that's really confusing me.

Answer (score 302, accepted):

## All About OpenGL Objects

The standard model for OpenGL objects is as follows.

Objects have state. Think of them as a `struct`. So you might have an object defined like this:

```cpp
struct Object
{
    int count;
    float opacity;
    char *name;
};
```

The object has certain values stored in it and it has *state*. OpenGL objects have state too.

### Changing State

In C/C++, if you have an instance of type `Object`, you would change its state as follows: `obj.count = 5;` You would directly reference an instance of the object, get the particular piece of state you want to change, and shove a value into it.

In OpenGL, you *don't* do this.

For legacy reasons better left unexplained, to change the state of an OpenGL object, you must first *bind* it to the context. This is done with some from of `glBind*` call.

The C/C++ equivalent to this is as follows:

```cpp
Object *g_objs[MAX_LOCATIONS] = {NULL};    
void BindObject(int loc, Object *obj)
{
  g_objs[loc] = obj;
}
```

Textures are interesting; they represent a special case of binding. Many `glBind*` calls have a "target" parameter. This represents different locations in the OpenGL context where objects of that type can be bound. For example, you can bind a framebuffer object for reading (`GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`) or for writing (`GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`). This affects how OpenGL uses the buffer. This is what the `loc` parameter above represents.

Textures are special because when you *first* bind them to a target, they get special information. When you first bind a texture as a `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, you are actually setting special state in the texture. You are saying that this texture is a 2D texture. And it will *always* be a 2D texture; this state cannot be changed *ever*. If you have a texture that was first bound as a `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, you must *always* bind it as a `GL_TEXTURE_2D`; attempting to bind it as `GL_TEXTURE_1D` will give rise to an error (while run-time).

Once the object is bound, its state can be changed. This is done via generic functions specific to that object. They too take a location that represents which object to modify.

In C/C++, this looks like:

```cpp
void ObjectParameteri(int loc, ObjectParameters eParam, int value)
{
  if(g_objs[loc] == NULL)
    return;

  switch(eParam)
  {
    case OBJECT_COUNT:
      g_objs[loc]->count = value;
      break;
    case OBJECT_OPACITY:
      g_objs[loc]->opacity = (float)value;
      break;
    default:
      //INVALID_ENUM error
      break;
  }
}
```

Notice how this function sets whatever happens to be in currently bound `loc` value.

For texture objects, the main texture state changing functions are [`glTexParameter`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexParameter). The only other functions that change texture state are the [`glTexImage`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexImage2D) functions and their variations ([`glCompressedTexImage`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glCompressedTexImage2D), [`glCopyTexImage`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glCopyTexImage2D), the recent [`glTexStorage`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexStorage2D)). The various `SubImage` versions change the contents of the texture, but they do not technically change its *state*. The `Image` functions allocate texture storage and set the texture's format; the `SubImage` functions just copy pixels around. That is not considered the texture's state.

Allow me to repeat: these are the **only** functions that modify texture state. `glTexEnv` modifies environment state; it doesn't affect anything stored in texture objects.

### Active Texture

The situation for textures is more complex, again for legacy reasons best left undisclosed. This is where [`glActiveTexture`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glActiveTexture) comes in.

For textures, there aren't just targets (`GL_TEXTURE_1D`, `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`, etc). There are also texture *units*. In terms of our C/C++ example, what we have is this:

```cpp
Object *g_objs[MAX_OBJECTS][MAX_LOCATIONS] = {NULL};
int g_currObject = 0;

void BindObject(int loc, Object *obj)
{
  g_objs[g_currObject][loc] = obj;
}

void ActiveObject(int currObject)
{
  g_currObject = currObject;
}
```

Notice that now, we not only have a 2D list of `Object`s, but we also have the concept of a current object. We have a function to set the current object, we have the concept of a maximum number of current objects, and all of our object manipulation functions are adjusted to select from the current object.

When you change the currently active object, you change the entire set of target locations. So you can bind something that goes into current object 0, switch to current object 4, and will be modifying a completely different object.

This analogy with texture objects is perfect... almost.

See, `glActiveTexture` does not take an integer; it takes an *enumerator*. Which in theory means that it can take anything from `GL_TEXTURE0` to `GL_TEXTURE31`. But there's one thing you must understand:

**THIS IS FALSE!**

The actual range that `glActiveTexture` can take is governed by `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`. That is the maximum number of simultaneous multitextures that an implementation allows. These are each divided up into different groupings for different shader stages. For example, on GL 3.x class hardware, you get 16 vertex shader textures, 16 fragment shader textures, and 16 geometry shader textures. Therefore, `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` will be 48.

But there aren't 48 enumerators. Which is why `glActiveTexture` doesn't really take enumerators. The **correct** way to call `glActiveTexture` is as follows:

```cpp
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
```

where `i` is a number between 0 and `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`.

### Rendering

So what does all of this have to do with rendering?

When using shaders, you set your sampler uniforms to a texture image unit (`glUniform1i(samplerLoc, i)`, where `i` is the image unit). That represents the number you used with `glActiveTexture`. The sampler will pick the target based on the sampler type. So a `sampler2D` will pick from the `GL_TEXTURE_2D` target. This is one reason why samplers have different types.

Now this sounds suspiciously like you can have two GLSL samplers, with different *types* that use the same texture image unit. But you can't; OpenGL forbids this and will give you an error when you attempt to render.

Comment: Wow! Yet another wonderful answer - thanks Nicol! I especially like that paragraph about a 2D texture *always* being a 2D texture. I'm building a wrapper around some of these things now, and I wasn't sure if I should leave that open to change. And the part about `GL_TEXTURE0 + i` -- I was meaning to inspect the enum values to see if that was valid or not. And the last paragraph - didn't know if that was legal or not. Excellent! I'm bookmarking all your answers so I can refer to them again.

Comment: Is `glGenerateMipmap` part of the set of functions that change state or is it part of the set of functions that change content?

Comment: Any idea why openGL forbids different types of GLSL samplers to the same texture unit? Is it a legacy reason?

Comment: @dev_nut: You have it backwards. The "legacy reason" is what makes the API seem like it should be allowed. That is, the texture's type being part of the binding target. Note that more modern texture binding functions like [`glBindTextures`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindTextures) (note the "s") don't take a texture target as a parameter. That's how the hardware works; a texture unit is a piece of hardware that accesses a texture. A *single* texture. The API was simply poorly designed originally.

Comment: Never explain something by saying how it is, and then saying "but that's completely false".  There's no more guaranteed way to make people learn the wrong thing.

Comment: Excellent answer, @NicolBolas. Another great explanation can be found [here](http://bastiaanolij.blogspot.de/2016/01/glactivetexture.html).

Answer (score 23):

I'll give it a try! All this is not that complicated, just a question of terms, hope I'll make myself clear.

---

You can create roughly as many *Texture Objects* as there is available memory in your system. These objects hold the actual data (texels) of your textures, along with parameters, provided by *glTexParameter* (see [FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/texture.htm#text0070)).

When being created, you have to assign one *Texture Target* to one texture object, which represents the type of the texture (`GL_TEXTURE_2D`, `GL_TEXTURE_3D`, `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE`, ...).

These two items, *texture object* and *texture target* represent the texture data. We'll come back to them later.

**Texture units**

Now, OpenGL provides an array of *texture units*, that can be used simultaneously while drawing. The size of the array depends of the OpenGL system, yours has 8.

You can *bind* a texture object to a texture unit to use the given texture while drawing.

In a simple and easy world, to draw with a given texture, you'd bind a texture object to the texture unit, and you'd do (pseudocode):

```cpp
glTextureUnit[0] = textureObject
```

As GL is a state machine, it, alas, does not work this way. Supposing that our `textureObject` has data for the `GL_TEXTURE_2D` texture target, we'll express the previous assignment as:

```cpp
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);                   // select slot 0 of the texture units array
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObject);    // do the binding
```

Note that `GL_TEXTURE_2D` really depends on the type of the texture you want to bind.

**Texture objects**

In pseudo code, to set texture data or texture parameters, you'd do for example:

```cpp
setTexData(textureObject, ...)
setTexParameter(textureObject, TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, LINEAR)
```

OpenGL can't directly manipulate texture objects, to update/set their content, or change their parameters, you have to first bind them to the active texture unit (whichever it is). The equivalent code becomes:

```cpp
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObject)       // this 'installs' textureObject in texture unit
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
```

**Shaders**

Shaders have access to all the texture units, they don't care about the active texture.

Sampler uniforms are `int` values representing the index of the texture unit to use for the sampler (and *not* the texture object to use).

So you have to bind your texture objects to the units you want to use.

The type of the sampler will do the match with the texture target that is used in the texture unit: `Sampler2D` for `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, and so on...

Comment: One thing I don't understand. Let's assume I have some texture and it is used in many shaders on different texture units. Let's assume I want to change texture filtering on run time. What texture unit should I use? Can I change texture state on Unit 0 and then use that texture on different unit?

Comment: @majakthecoder In my answer, I consider the filtering as a property of the *texture object* - which means you can't change it specifically in a texture unit. Depending of the flavor of OpenGL you're targetting, you may be able to *sampler objects* to solve this problem (https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object), otherwise, you may have to duplicate the texture object, to have multiple simultaneous filterings.

Answer (score 12):

Imagine the GPU like some paint processing plant.

There are a number of tanks, which delivers dye to some painting machine. In the painting machine the dye is then applied to the object. Those tanks are the *texture units*

Those tanks can be equipped with different kinds of dye. Each kind of dye requires some other kind of solvent. The "solvent" is the *texture target*. For convenience each tank is connected to some solvent supply, and but only one kind of solvent can be used at a time in each tank. So there's a valve/switch `TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`, `TEXTURE_3D`, `TEXTURE_2D`, `TEXTURE_1D`. You can fill all the dye types into the tank at the same time, but since only one kind of solvent goes in, it will "dilute" only the kind of dye matching. So you can have each kind of texture being bound, but the binding with the "most important" solvent will actually go into the tank and mix with the kind of dye it belongs to.

And then there's the dye itself, which comes from a warehouse and is filled into the tank by "binding" it. That's your texture.

Comment: Kind of a strange analogy...I'm not sure it really clears anything up. Especially the part about the "diluting" and "most important solvent". You're saying if I bind both a 2d texture and 3d texture, I can only use one of them, or what? Which one would be deemed most important?

Comment: @Mark: Well, I was trying to speak in terms of a painter who works with literal dye (say oil based and water based). Anyway, yes if you bind and enable multiple texture targets there's precedence: CUBE_MAP > 3D > TEXTURE_ARRAY > 2D > 1D.

Comment: Neat! I didn't know about the precedence. Makes more sense now that I know only one texture target can be used per texture unit.

Comment: @datenwolf: Can you please elaborate on where this precedence comes into play? I cannot work it out myself. If I've GL_TEXTURE_UNIT0 active, to which I bind two texture objects for targets CUBE_MAP and 2D, where will they take precedence? In the fragment shader, I anyways create a sampler based on the dimension i.e. sampler2D or samplerCube, so how would this precedence come in to play? Am I missing something or was it once used during the fixed-function times?

Comment: @legends2k: When you bind a texture unit to a sampler uniform, the sampler type must match the type of the precedenting texture bound that texture unit.

Comment: @datenwolf: Yes, so where's the texture target precedence coming here, I should anyway explicitly specify the type when giving the uniform, so how does CUBE_MAP > 3D > TEXTURE_ARRAY > 2D > 1D matter?

Comment: @legends2k: Well, now it's getting interesting. Are we talking about the core or the compatibility profile. Do we assume ideal, or buggy drivers. In theory the type of the uniform selects which target of the texture unit to select. In practice this happens in core profile. In compatibility profile expect some buggy drivers to present you with the all white default texture if the preceding target of the texture unit doesn't match the type of the sampler.

Comment: @legends2k: Also, think about what would happen if there were a 2D and a 3D texture bound to the same unit and you had a 2D and a 3D sampler uniform, which you bind to the same unit? You can trigger all kinds of weird driver bugs with this. In practice thinking in the old fixed function precedence model keeps your mind sane and your program working, because that's how most drivers will behave in a predictable way.

Comment: @datenwolf: Aargh, it finally boils down to the profiles and how good the drivers are implemented, got it! Thanks :)