# Does glGenTextures and glBindTexture needs to be called before doing glTexImage2D and glTexSubImage2D

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glteximage2d

Hi I have 35 images to draw in a display. I am drawing it in 7X5 grid. The images are downloaded from internet. Each time an image is downloaded I try to draw the whole 35 images. But some of them are not downloaded yet. So I draw some default tile for them instead. The problem is every time an image is downloaded I am drawing the previously drawn images again too. I want to reduce it. So I was thinking about doing something like Texture Atlas. I am trying to do it manually. I am doing it by making a big image with `glTexImage2D` and adding subimages to it with `glTexSubImage2D`.

```
glGenTextures(1, tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (*tex));
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, textureImageInfo->format, textureImageInfo->texWidth, textureImageInfo->texHeight, 0, textureImageInfo->format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, textureImageInfo->imageWidth, textureImageInfo->imageHeight, textureImageInfo->format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureImageInfo->image);
```

I call 35 `glTexSubImage2D` to add all 35 images to a big `glTexImage2D`. Here I wrote only one for easier explanation. Then finally I do

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, this->tileCoordList); 
glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, this->tileTextureCoordList);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Now what I am confused with is do I need to generate and bind textures 35 times too for 35 call of `glTexSubImage2D` ?? Or just doing once is enough. The actual problem I don't understand whats binding the texture has got to do anything with it. Thanks.

Comment: If you only have one texture then you only need to get one texture name from glGenTextures() and one call to glBindTexture().

Comment: so I need 35 calls of glGenTextures() here? Because I am adding 35 texture subimages with `glTexSubImage2D`.

Comment: No. You have one texture.  `glTexSubImage` fills part of your one texture.

Comment: As for "*The actual problem I don't understand whats binding the texture has got to do anything with it.*", [I've answered that too often](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866904/need-help-understanding-the-differences-and-relationship-between-glactivetexture/8887844#8887844) to [keep answering it over and over again](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "subimage" in a texture. There are only images in a texture. `glTexImage2D` allocates storage for a particular image in the texture, and optionally uploads data to that image. `glTexSubImage2D` only uploads data to an image. The "sub" means that you can update *part* of the image, not necessarily all of it.

`glTexImage2D` is like `malloc` followed by `memcpy`. `glTexSubImage2D` is just a `memcpy`. That's why you have to call `glTexImage2D` first.