# OpenGL: What happens to a texture if I bind a new one to another target?

Tags: opengl, binding, textures, target

I'm currently learning some OpenGL theory. Now I got some questions of which I cant find an answer.

Here is one of my question: 
Lets assume, that I bind a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` to unit `GL_TEXTURE0` like this:

```
GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, myTexture1_ID);
```

Now I'm going to bind another one, but this time it's a `GL_TEXTURE_1D`.

```
GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_1D, myTexture2_ID);
```

What happens to the first binding call?
Does it unbind, because of the same texture unit or does it stay, because of the different texture target?

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend using `glBindTextures` instead. Lets you bind all the textures at once, clear the unneeded bindings, and avoids specifying texture targets explicitly after creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The texture binding to the target `GL_TEXTURE_2D` is left untouched as long as you are not rebinding another texture to the same target.

You can even bind multiple textures, each to a different "texture unit" by calling

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i)
```

before binding a new texture.

Comment: So I could bind a 1D, 2D and 3D texture to each unit from 0 to n at the same time, theoretically?

Comment: @bitQUAKE: Yes you can bind them at the same time, but not use them at the same time. There's a precedence between texture targets on a given texture unit and only the texture target with the highest precedence is being actively used.

Comment: Also very comprehensively explained by this user: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8887844/5790859 especially the part under "Active Texture"