# Can only use glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0) and not other texture units?

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

I am confused about textures and cubemaps in OpenGL.

Let's say I want basic texture mapping. I do:

```c
  GLuint texture0;
  glGenTextures(1, &texture0);
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);
```

and then I set up `glTexImage2D` and call `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "texture_sampler"), GL_TEXTURE0)` and all is well.

Now, I also want to use a cubemap for environment mapping. I thought, also using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866904/differences-and-relationship-between-glactivetexture-and-glbindtexture) as reference, that I should do like this:

```c
  GLuint texture1;
  glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+1); 
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture1);
```

and then `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "cubemap_sampler"), GL_TEXTURE0+1)`.

However, this does not work, and only renders a black object.
On the other hand, if I do not run `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+1)` but instead stick to `GL_TEXTURE0` everything is fine.

According to my understanding, this is not how it should be...

Can anyone shed some light as to what is going on?

I am using GLSL `#version 440`.

Comment: Shouldn't the argument to `glUniform1i` be the *offset* from `GL_TEXTURE0`?  So `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "cubemap_sampler"), 1)` . See ["Binding textures to samplers"](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Binding_textures_to_samplers).

Answer (score 1):

`glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "texture_sampler"),  GL_TEXTURE0+1)` is a strange idea.

The texture unit is the integral binding point between the texture object and the texture sampler.
`GL_TEXTURE0` is an enumerator constant for the use with [`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml). `GL_TEXTURE0` address the texture unit 0.
The value you need to set on the texture sampler uniform is the texture unit not, the "name" of the texture unit. Hence you have to set 0 rather then `GL_TEXTURE0`:

<s>`glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "texture_sampler"), GL_TEXTURE0+1)`</s>

```cpp
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "texture_sampler"), 1)
```

---

Note that the sampler bind point is 0 by default. The instruction `glUniform1i(...,  GL_TEXTURE0+1)` causes an `INVALID_VALUE` error and does not change the binding point at all.
See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 7.6.1 Loading Uniform Variables In The Default Uniform Block](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=163&zoom=100,168,173)

> An *INVALID_VALUE* error is generated if `Uniform1i{v}` is used to set a
> sampler uniform to a value less than zero or greater than or equal to the value
> of *MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS*.

Comment: Thanks. However, also `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+1); glUniform1i(env_sampler_location, 1);` renders a black object. But if I change it to  `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); glUniform1i(env_sampler_location, 0);`, it works.

Comment: @Supernormal You are not a new user. You now that the comment section is not intended to ask additional question. You know that you have [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Anyway, you are not providing enough information in the question  to spot the new issue.